# Making sure MockMvc.perform hasErrors

Tags: spring, mockito

I need the following to return true for hasErrors:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/user_save"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(model().hasErrors());
}
```

I figured out one way to this by calling userController.saveUser:

```
BindingResult mockBindingResult = mock(BindingResult.class);
    FieldError mockFieldError = mock(FieldError.class);

    when(mockBindingResult.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mockBindingResult.getFieldError()).thenReturn(mockFieldError);
    when(mockFieldError.getField()).thenReturn("mock error field");
    when(mockFieldError.getCode()).thenReturn("mock error code");

    User user = new User();
    String str = "test";
    user.setUsername(str);
    user.setPassword(str);
    user.setName(str);

    String result = userController.saveUser(user, mockBindingResult);
```

However, this is long, looks horrible and only indirectly lets me see if there's an error by way of the redirect (`result` takes on a different value if there's an error).

Surely there is a way of adapting the first solution of mockM?

Comment: The test does not make sense. `BindingResult.hasErrors()` will always yield `true` whatever happens in your controller. What are you trying to test?

Comment: Hmm, nope. My controller has "if (bindingResult.hasErrors())", which only executes if there are errors. As for the test, the user is redirected if there are errors, so I just need to check that the redirect (and a few other steps) are executed when hasErrors returns true. Currently it returns false.

Comment: You could pass a invalid user and check the view name using `MockMvcResult` returned by `andReturn()`.